# Storing user uploaded file in the web-server

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, tomcat

We are currently developing a web-application that lets user upload their audio files(any audio files,mp3,wav,ogg etc etc).

My question is, there are audio files that are not big enough for the database and it is not a good practice, my question is where should I place these audio files? Should I place them in a folder in the webserver or are there any alternatives like a file storage for java? Because putting these files in the database is not enough. I was thinking I'll just place the files in file path in the database. We are currently using tomcat server, and mysql database.

Comment: How can an audio file be "not big enough for the database"?  What does that even mean?

Comment: some audio files are around 200mb. and I belive blob is around 60kb?

Comment: That still doesn't make sense.  I think you mean "too big for the database".  For MySQL, LONGBLOB datatype can be 2^32 bytes (4GB) long assuming your network buffer size is set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to store the file in the web server itself then it may cause issues if you have multiple web servers. So if you want to store the file as it is, create a remote mount and mount it  using nfs in all servers with the same path. for eg: mount the remote storage in /mnt/audio_mount in all the servers so that you can access it from all servers.